# Deserializing variable Type JSON array using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string in this form:

```
string jsonStr = "[\"A\", [\"Martini\", \"alovell\"],[\"Martin\", \"lovell\"]]"
```

I am trying to deserialize the JSON using the C# .NET deserializer  DataContractJsonSerializer with the following code snippet

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStr));
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<X>);
X data = (X)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

Now since the JSON array is an array of variable types I do not know what  type of object
X should be

If my String were

```
jsonStr = "[[\"Martini\", \"alovell\"],[\"Martin\", \"lovell\"]]"
```

I could use this:

```
X = List<List<String>>
```

and that would work for me. I was wondering if there is any way to deserialize variable type JSON array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to do this.

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsonStr);
```

The JArray would contain either strings or nested JArray's depending on the JSON.

Comment: I use this assembly, and it's fantastic. I highly recommend this.