# Serializing a JSON array to an instance of a class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

If I have JSON data such as:

```
{
"datapoints":[ [null, 1234567890, "point1"], [null, 1234567890, "point2"] ]
}
```

Is there a way to deserialize that data into the following classes:

```
public class Result 
{
    public DataPoint[] DataPoints {get;set;}
}

public class DataPoint
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
   public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

Can I specify the index of which array member to serialize into which property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to some custom deserialization using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = @"{""datapoints"":[ [null, 1234567890, ""point1""], [null, 1234567890, ""point2""] ]}";
var result = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var dataPoints = result["datapoints"]
            .Select(t => new DataPoint() 
             {
                Timestamp = String.IsNullOrEmpty(t[0].ToString()) ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.Parse(t[0].ToString()),
                Value = t[1].ToString(),
                Name= t[2].ToString()
             })
            .ToArray();
```

PS: `Timestamp` may need some more work depending on the format.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing now. I just wondered if there was a more direct method to deserialize rather than needing to enumerate the list again to parse the array values.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly, since you're not specifying how you're deserializing the data.

If using external libraries is a possibility, I'd recommend using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) - it's a lot nicer to use than *System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer*.

Edit to address (very valid!) concerns - as mentioned [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215479/deserializing-variable-type-json-array-using-datacontractjsonserializer), if you include Json.Net, you'd be able to say `JArray a = JArray.Parse(datapoints);` to load up your arrays, and then you'd manually `new` up new DataPoints for each new array item and populate it with values from the expected slots.  I'm not aware of attributes that you could decorate your class properties with that would make that any prettier.  You could likely use its Linq to Json to make this a less ugly affair.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. Currently, I'm using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` (different from `JavaScripSerializer`).

Comment: "Use an external library" really isn't an answer.

Comment: Per your edit, I can also just use `DataContractJsonSerializer` to parse data into `object[]` and not add the dependency or learning curve of Json.Net. I wanted to know if something could directly translate between the array and my class.

Comment: @scottm - quite right about being able to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` in the same way - you'd be able to use it to get to the intermediate multidimensional array of strings stage and from there, use Linq to instantiate a bunch of new objects.  I just thought I'd mention Json.Net as `JavaScriptSerializer` has, um, character.