# Deserialize multi-type JSON array using DataContracts

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

Currently, I have some JSON data that I am attempting to deserialize using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class. However, one of the arrays in the data contains multiple types of objects. Is there a way to deserialize this data properly? I am aware that [a very similar question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1215479), but **I would prefer not to use Json.NET or any other third-party libraries.**

**EDIT:** A small example:

In this instance, let's say the JSON is of form `[{"foo":string},{"bar":string},{"foo":string},{"foo":string},...]` where each element is either of form `{"foo":string}` or `{"bar":string}`. Then, the contracts could be set up as such:

```
[DataContract]
class Foo { [DataMember] public string foo; }

[DataContract]
class Bar { [DataMember] public string bar; }
```

In this context, my question is, **how do I deserialize this array of `Foo`s and `Bar`s?**

Comment: `However, one of the arrays in the data contains multiple types of objects` -- could you provide an example?  How are these object types different?  If for some reason they are completely different you may consider `dynamic` type.  Posting a sample of the JSON and the model you are attempting to deserialize it to would be helpful.

Comment: @ShaneRay Added a small example, in the real case, my `Foo` and `Bar` have completely different properties.

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound right.  There should not be two completely different types in a single array.  Given the JSON provided I would try something like this....

```
[DataContract]
class SomeClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string foo { get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string bar { get; set;}
}
```

Then check for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` on each property.

Updated with more code...

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass[] output;
        var json = "[{\"foo\":\"value\"},{\"bar\":\"value\"},{\"foo\":\"value1\"},{\"foo\":\"value1\"}]";

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SomeClass[]));
             output = (SomeClass[])deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }

        // do something with output
        Console.WriteLine(output.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Specifically, I am querying a certain JSON web API which gives 2 responses (with different formats) in an array.

Comment: In that case you need to have two separate models.  For the first API call that returns an array you deserialize to `ModelA`.  The second API call you deserialize to `ModelB`.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm trying to say. I pass one request to the server, and receive a single response with an array with a `Foo` and a `Bar`. I'm asking here how to deserialize this array to retrieve the `Foo` and `Bar` in it.

Comment: The JSON you provided is an array of objects...  It sounds like you may be referring to a dictionary but `foo` is repeated so it can not be an indexer.  I have updated my answer with more example code.

Comment: So pretty much, the only solution is to create a union of the two and set the array type to that?

Comment: That is the best solution I can come up with given the provided data.  If I had an example endpoint or a better example of the JSON returned there may be other options.

Comment: If this answer helped solve your problem, please mark as "answered".

Comment: I will, just waiting a day or two to make sure no better answers crop up.